# Uninstall PhpStorm on Windows

Tags: phpstorm, uninstallation

I read the comments here about uninstalling PhpStorm on Ubuntu and it implies uninstalling PhpStorm is actually a deleting process.

I installed the JetBrains ToolKit and accidentally installed PhpStorm which gets installed into an AppData path and I don't want it there. PhpStorm is not in Programs and Features to uninstall. The ToolKit was there and it uninstalled as expected.

I observed the downloaded instance PhpStorm-2016.3.2.exe will install to Program Files as expected.

There is no PhpStorm entry in the registry. Again, this implies a portable install that can be installed and deleted on demand which also implies I can copy and paste to a new location.

Is this correct or is there some other way I must learn to uninstall the instance installed in the AppData path so I can reinstall using the PhpStorm-2016.3.2.exe download or can I copy and paste to a new location?

Comment: Simply speaking: location of binary files does not matter, but config files will still be searched in default (for this OS) specific location: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs (which you can override)

Comment: The link to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs is in fact sufficient to close this inquiry thank you.